# Resetting a Git Project

Tags: git, github

I want to completely rewrite a project from scratch (in fact use a completely different language), yet I want to keep all the former git commits for reference. What would be the best way to approach this?

As a note, this project is connected to github, and I want to keep the code under the same repository while keeping all previous commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open a new branch as orphan branch and it will not be related to the "old code"

```
git checkout --orphan -b <new_branch>
```

> `--orphan <new_branch>`
>
> Create a new orphan branch, named , started from  and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.